# How do I fix the error "Media Type Not Found" when attempting to load a sector with int 13h ah=02h?

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader, bios, osdev

I have some code to load the second sector from a floppy disk in real mode, but int 0x13 fails with error "media type not found". Why is this?

I've tried to change the cylinders, heads and sectors from 0, 0 and 2 to 1, 1 and 1 respectively, to no avail (I don't know if CHS addressing uses 0 or 1 to start). I've also redone this code many times to organise it better in to functions, to no avail. It fails but does not print my error string, which puzzles me. It always seems to fail with the same error.

Here is the code:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

start:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00
    mov si, msg

    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10

    call reset_disk
    mov si, suc_reset
    call puts

    call load_stage2
    mov si, suc_load
    call puts

    hlt

; routine to reset disk state
reset_disk:
    xor ah, ah          ; int 0x13 ah = 0x00
    xor dl, dl          ; drive 0
    int 0x13
    jc .error           ; error if carry flag is set
    ret
.error:
    mov si, err_reset
    call puts
    hlt

; routine to load stage 2
load_stage2:
    mov ah, 0x02        ; int 0x13 ah = 0x02 (read sectors)
    mov al, 0x01        ; number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x01        ; cylinder 0
    mov cl, 0x02        ; sector 2
    xor dh, dh          ; head 0
    xor dl, dl          ; drive 0
    mov bx, 0x9c00      ; address 9c00
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx          ; 0x9c00:0x0000

    int 0x13
    or ah, ah
    jnz .error
    ret
.error:
    mov si, err_load
    call puts
    hlt

; routine to print a string
puts:
    mov ah, 0x0e        ; int 0x10 ah = 0x0e (putchar)
.loop:
    lodsb               ; load string byte from si
    or al, al           ; check if al is zero
    jz .end             ; if zero jump to end (null terminator)
    int 0x10            ; print character
    jmp .loop           ; loop
.end:
    ret

err_reset: db "Failed to reset disk", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
err_load: db "Failed to load stage 2", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
suc_reset: db "Successfully reset disk 0...", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
suc_load: db "Successfully loaded stage 2...", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
msg: db "Test", 0
times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

I expect the output to be the success message but also for `EAX` to be zero (indicating success).

Comment: What happens if you skip the reset disk command? Inside the bootsector code from a popular operating system there is also no reset disk call.

Comment: @E.vanPutten It does not work either.

Comment: What kind of simulator (or real hardware) are you running this on? If you are booting from USB, perhaps the drive number is not 0 but something else.

Comment: @E.vanPutten I am using qemu-system-i386 on macOS mojave

Comment: If you also have a harddisk configured in qemu, can you read a sector from that device instead (DL will have to be set to 80 hex instead of 00 hex I presume)?

Comment: How do you build your disk image (the commands to put the boot sector and the second sector into a disk image). hat is the command line you use to run qemu?

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks! I've decided to use 42h and the load seems to work (as it prints the success message when the amount to read is one sector but prints the error when it's more, as it should) but the file is not in the expected memory address. As for building, I just `cat` the two files with the bootsector first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of potential issues:

- You hard code the drive number to 0 (with `xor dl, dl`). Doing this means your code will not work if you launch QEMU in such a way that doesn't use Floppy Drive A (FDA). If you boot as a hard drive it will fail. The BIOS puts the drive number booted from in *DL* before it transfers control to your bootloader. Just use that value instead. This is easily achieved in your code by removing both occurrences of `xor dl, dl`
- You copy *CS* to the other segment registers. On some hardware and emulators *CS* may not be 0 (on some it may be 0x07c0). Do not rely on *CS* being a specific value. Because you use an origin point (`org 0x7c00`) you need to put 0 in the segment registers (especially *DS*).
- In Cylinder, Head, Sector addressing (CHS) the cylinders are 0 based, heads are 0 based, and only the sector numbers are 1 based. The second sector on a disk is CHS=(0,0,2). Your code as shown read CHS=(1,0,2) which is incorrect.
- The `HLT` instruction only waits until the next interrupt occurs. When an interrupt (ie: the timer) occurs the processor will continue executing the code after the `HLT`. You will want to turn off external interrupts with `CLI` before doing `HLT`. You should also put the `HLT` in a loop because it is possible on real hardware that Non-Maskable Interrupts (NMIs) can occur. To use `HLT` properly you could do:

  ```
      cli
  .hltloop:
      hlt
      jmp .hltloop
  ```

  Alternatively for a bootloader a simple infinite loop suffices: `jmp $`.

---

With these kinds of changes to your code, and a simple second stage for test purposes we can create code that reads the second stage to memory 0x9c00:0x0000 and then FAR JMP to it and execute the code. In this example `MDP` will be displayed directly on the display with white on magenta attributes.

**boot.asm**:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

start:
    mov ax, cs
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7c00

    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10

    call reset_disk
    mov si, suc_reset
    call puts

    call load_stage2
    mov si, suc_load
    call puts

    ; As a test if stage2 is loaded jump to code contained in stage2
    jmp 0x9c00:0x0000
;    jmp halt


; routine to reset disk state
reset_disk:
    xor ah, ah          ; int 0x13 ah = 0x00
    int 0x13
    jc .error           ; error if carry flag is set
    ret
.error:
    mov si, err_reset
    call puts
    jmp halt

; routine to load stage 2
load_stage2:
    mov ah, 0x02        ; int 0x13 ah = 0x02 (read sectors)
    mov al, 0x01        ; number of sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x00        ; cylinder 0
    mov cl, 0x02        ; sector 2
    xor dh, dh          ; head 0
    mov bx, 0x9c00      ; address 9c00
    mov es, bx
    xor bx, bx          ; 0x9c00:0x0000

    int 0x13
    or ah, ah
    jnz .error
    ret
.error:
    mov si, err_load
    call puts

halt:
    cli
.hltloop:
    hlt
    jmp .hltloop

; routine to print a string
puts:
    mov ah, 0x0e        ; int 0x10 ah = 0x0e (putchar)
.loop:
    lodsb               ; load string byte from si
    or al, al           ; check if al is zero
    jz .end             ; if zero jump to end (null terminator)
    int 0x10            ; print character
    jmp .loop           ; loop
.end:
    ret

err_reset: db "Failed to reset disk", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
err_load: db "Failed to load stage 2", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
suc_reset: db "Successfully reset disk 0...", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0
suc_load: db "Successfully loaded stage 2...", 0x0a, 0x0d, 0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

**stage2.asm**:

```
org 0x0000
bits 16

stage2:
    ; Display MDP with white on magenta on 4th line of text display
    mov ax, 0xb800
    mov es, ax
    mov word [es:480], 0x57<<8 | 'M'
    mov word [es:482], 0x57<<8 | 'D'
    mov word [es:484], 0x57<<8 | 'P'

    jmp $
```

I usually use DD to create disk images, but since you are using CAT you can assemble and build the disk image with:

```
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
nasm -f bin stage2.asm -o stage2.bin
cat boot.bin stage2.bin >disk.img
```

You can run QEMU and boot from either floppy (FDA) or hard disk (HDA). It should work using either:

```
qemu-system-i386 -fda disk.img
```

or:

```
qemu-system-i386 -hda disk.img
```

If it works properly the output should look similar to:

[image]

Comment: But what was the reason that INT 13,02 call failed. Was it the drive index or the segment registers pointing to the wrong memory location?

Comment: @E.vanPutten : I couldn't specifically answer that because it was unclear. My way around that was showing how to invoke QEMU. Part of me believes the likely culprit was the boot drive being used wasn't 0. If he ran `qemu-system-i386 disk.img` then that would boot off of HDA and would likely fail the way he was seeing. My tests suggested it was likely the wrong drive being accessed. Reading outside the disk image would likely cause a different error (but it can vary between emulators). The segment register ES and BX (offset) were correct for Int 13h/ah=2 to work.

Comment: The issue with copying CS to DS wasn't an issue under QEMU and wasn't a cause of the problems he saw. Under real hardware and emulators in specific cases it could have caused problems. Most likely thing he would have seen with such a failure would have been none of the strings being displayed.

Comment: Exactly. And seeing that media error further supports your theory that it wasn't the floppy that was being booted from. In a comment I asked him to try the first HDA. I still wonder if that made his test pass.

Comment: @E.vanPutten His code would read the disk if it was started with with `-fda` option (since he set DL to 0, booting from floppy disk A should work). In a comment I long since deleted (after making a formal answer) I asked what command he used to launch QEMU but he didn't respond to that (he answered other things I asked). I suspect however he launched QEMU  booting as a hard disk instead of floppy.

Comment: Which is why I asked to try 80 hex as drive number. Because if that had worked we'd have the strong hint that the virtual floppy is not there or under another drive no (such as what happens with CDROM drives and USB floppy adapters etc)

Comment: @E.vanPutten I'm not disagreeing with you. Your suggestion in the comments under the question were legitimate. I took the more robust approach to make the code work by letting the BIOS tell us what drive to use rather than hard coding it.

Comment: Your answer is perfect which is why I upvoted. I just wondered what the OP saw exactly.